# jq: partition based on a filter

Tags: json, group-by, jq, data-partitioning

Let's say I have the following:

```
jq 'map(select(. >= 5))'
```

given `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` it returns:

```
[5,6,7]
```

I also have

```
jq 'map(select(. < 5))'
```

which given the same data, returns `[1,2,3,4]`. How can I do these complementary queries at the same time, so that I receive for example:

```
[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jq has a built-in filter for grouping by some (possibly multi-valued) criterion:

```
jq -nc '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] | group_by(. < 5)'
```

produces:

```
[[5,6,7],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: oh it has support for groupBy out of the box! lovely :) How do I get the length of each of these partitions? I tried `| map(.length)` but it didn't work
ie I want to get [3,4]

Comment: You could use `map(length)` to get the lengths of the groups (notice, no dot).

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm still struggling with manipulation of nested lists. I have asked this separate question which are the minimal versions of the problems i am trying to solve.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179292/jq-groupby-and-nested-json-arrays

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `reduce`:

```
reduce .[] as $x
([]; if $x < 5 then .[0] += [$x] else .[1] += [$x] end)
```

This will produce:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

Comment: To save typing, one could write `[]` to initialize the accumulator :-)