# jq: groupby and nested json arrays

Tags: json, group-by, jq, data-partitioning

Let's say I have: `[[1,2], [3,9], [4,2], [], []]`

I would like to know the scripts to get:

- The number of nested lists which are/are not non-empty. ie want to get: `[3,2]`
- The number of nested lists which contain or not contain number 3. ie want to get: `[1,4]`
- The number of nested lists for which the sum of the elements is/isn't less than `4`. ie want to get: `[3,2]`

ie basic examples of nested data partition.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes and I can't get it to work or else I wouldn't have asked. :)

Comment: Then you should share your failed attempts with us, *give me teh codez* questions are highly discouraged here

Comment: "Give me the code" questions for well stablished languages like java and c++ is discouraged yes. Also, this is clearly not my original problem. It's clearly a MCVE. I'd encourage you to take the approach 'peak' has taken.

Comment: Nah, I wouldn't answer such a question regardless of the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since stackoverflow.com is not a coding service, I'll confine this response to the first question, with the hope that it will convince you that learning jq is worth the effort.

Let's begin by refining the question about the counts of the lists 
"which are/are not empty" to emphasize that the first number in the answer should correspond to the number of empty lists (2), and the second number to the rest (3).  That is, the required answer should be `[2,3]`.

### Solution using built-in filters

The next step might be to ask whether `group_by` can be used.  If the ordering did not matter, we could simply write:

```
group_by(length==0) | map(length)
```

This returns `[3,2]`, which is not quite what we want.  It's now worth checking the documentation about what `group_by` is supposed to do. On checking the details at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions,
we see that by design `group_by` does indeed sort by the grouping value.

Since in jq, `false < true`, we could fix our first attempt by writing:

```
group_by(length > 0) | map(length)
```

That's nice, but since `group_by` is doing so much work when all we really need is a way to count, it's clear we should be able to come up with a more efficient (and hopefully less opaque) solution.

### An efficient solution

At its core the problem boils down to counting, so let's define a generic `tabulate` filter for producing the counts of distinct string values.  Here's a def that will suffice for present purposes:

```
# Produce a JSON object recording the counts of distinct
# values in the given stream, which is assumed to consist 
# solely of strings.
def tabulate(stream):
  reduce stream as $s ({}; .[$s] += 1);
```

An efficient solution can now be written down in just two lines:

```
tabulate(.[] | length==0 | tostring )
| [.["true", "false"]]
```

QED

### p.s.

The function named `tabulate` above is sometimes called `bow` (for "bag of words").  In some ways, that would be a better name, especially as it would make sense to reserve the name `tabulate` for similar functionality that would work for arbitrary streams.

Comment: Why not just `reduce .[] as $x ([]; if $x==[] then .[0]+=1 else .[1]+=1 end)`? This way you don't need sort and map

Comment: Sure, but my main goal here, as suggested at the outset, is not to solve a particular problem.

Comment: That's a great walkthrough. Thanks a lot @peak